# I need top constraint of unknow element

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have an app which is downloading image from server by clicking the button. After image have downloaded i create a new imageView and add it to the my contentView(UIView). I need to create the constraints - every new imageview need top constraint from previous one

```
func addNewImageToTheScrollView(img: UIImage?) {
    if let imageResponse = img {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageResponse.crop(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: imageResponse.size.height/2, width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: 200)))
        self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let x = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)

        self.contentView.addConstraints([x, y])
        imageView.addConstraints([width, height])
    }
}
```

If i comment the constraint code, it will be work fine unless every new imageView will be on the same place, on the top of the View. Now whit this constraint code i have such code issue after downloading

> 2017-07-02 14:50:01.018 ImageFromServerTest[11516:1080948] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for >: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs.'

Comment: This isn't a direct solution to your problem, but you might consider using either a `UITableView` or `UIStackView`. :-) Or a `UIStackView` in a `UIScrollView`, adding the images to the Stackview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are working with scrollViews, there are 2 thumb rules for it:-

1. Give the scrollView leading, trailing, bottom, and top constraint with respect to the superview, that is `self.view`

   ```
    @IbOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

       let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

       let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

       let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

       let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
   ```
2. Add constraints to the contentView with respect to the scrollView

   ```
   @IbOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

     //increase the constant according to how much long you need the scrollview to be
    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
   ```

Now add your subviews constraints (labels, images) with respect to the contentView

For example- You received your first image, so we will maintain an array of UIImageViews outside your function.

```
var imageViews = [UIImageViews]() //declared outside the function


    //received an image here
        var imageView = UIImageView() // define the frame according to yourself using frame init method
        imageView.image = image

    if imageViews.isEmpty { // first image view 
    //add constraints to first image view

    let x = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)
    }

else { //second, third, fourth image view... so on

    let x = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageViews[imageViews.count - 1], attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)

    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)
}

      imageViews.append(imageView) 
}
```

Hope you got an idea now, how to proceed with this problem. If having more than 4 or 5 imageviews, you'll probably want to check the count of the array and increase the contentView of the scrollView accordingly. you can do so by using 
`self.scrollView.contentSize  = CGSize(width, height)`

Comment: Up voted. I had a comment ready to post saying some of this, but decided it was more of an answer. But then I realized there was more to it (from the other things implied in the OP) than my "answer" provided - so I just didn't post anything. Nice job of explaining the various pieces of of properly setting things up in a UIScrollView.

Comment: you are great, thanks)) i think it will be a lot time for me to understand about if else constraints myself))

Comment: yeah, it takes time to understand things.. btw I recommend you to follow this channel and enhance your skills... https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem here:

```
let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)
```

"toItem" parameter should have some value. Also first parameter should be imageView.topAnchor. Probably it should look something like this:

```
let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView.topAnchor, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView.topAnchor, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)
```

Comment: it didn't help (

Comment: 2017-07-02 15:42:51.208 ImageFromServerTest[12886:1114489] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x608000464c00 "UIImageView:0x7fa81de0faf0.top">: Unknown layout attribute'